# Custom theme breaks spinner apperance

Tags: android

I am currently working on dynamically changing themes with a settings option. The themes are very simple and only change background color. After changing theme, the spinners do not look right see image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/baddropdown.png/
I solved the first issue (the spinner itself) with a custom spinner item that sets the background transparent

```
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:ellipsize="marquee" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:singleLine="true" 
     style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle" 
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:id="@android:id/text1" />
```

I tried the same with a custom spinner_dropdown_item but it did not work.  Any ideas what I can try to get the default spinner appearance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I was able to change the spinner_dropdown_item background http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/10/halfbaddropdown.png/ but the drop down prompt background and separators are the application backgrounds color but I want the default appearance.
NOTE: removed an image link so I could post the newest.

EDIT: Issue has been resolved, acctually ended up being a simple fix. Had to change my custom theme which was

```
    <style name="grey" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:background">#EEE9E9</item>
    </style>
```

in styles.xml to

```
    <style name="grey" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/converter_grey</item>
    </style>
```

and define the color in colors.xml

Answer (score 3):

Issue has been resolved, acctually ended up being a simple fix. Had to change my custom theme which was

```
<style name="grey" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:background">#EEE9E9</item>
</style>
```

in styles.xml to

```
<style name="grey" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/converter_grey</item>
</style>
```

and define the color in colors.xml